# How to backup MSSQL to NAS storage with local credentials

Tags: sql-server, synology

I have Synology NAS with local credentials authentication. How can I create a backup from MSSQL to such share? My only option is to authenticate with username/password combo since the Synology UI does not allow adding anything else.

Comment: Manually or programmatically? Is your NAS joined into the Active Directory?

Comment: I would like to use the backup features in the MSSQL. NAS is only with local accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If scheduling a task with powershell is an option you could write a script using [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/)

Mount the share as a drive with [Net use](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/gg651155(v=ws.11)) and use dbatools command [Backup-DbaDatabase](https://docs.dbatools.io/Backup-DbaDatabase) to backup to this drive.

You could even use the SQL Servers Agent by creating a [Powershell type step](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/run-windows-powershell-steps-in-sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver16) in a job.

I guess it'd even be possible to add the credentials to the Credential Manager and directly backup to UNC path without mounting first.

**Backup to network drive with default tools** (would not recommend)

You'd need to execute this prior to your backup operation. Also: I've never used this to perform regular backups. Works fine though for occasional usage.

Source: [Make Network Path Visible For SQL Server Backup and Restore in SSMS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3499/make-network-path-visible-for-sql-server-backup-and-restore-in-ssms/)

**activate xp-cmdshell**

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

**connect drive**

MSSQL 2008

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use /user:[Domain]\[Username] H: \\RemoteServerName\ShareName [Password]'
```

MSSQL 2012 +

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use H: \\RemoteServerName\ShareName'
```

**delete drive**

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use H: /delete'
```

Comment: Powershell is not an option for me. I would like to use the buillt-in backup mechanisms so I can configure data retention etc.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Although this could also be handled in the script. For example by searching for the files with Get-ChildItem query by LastWriteTime property and pipe it into Remove-Item.
There is a way to make network drives accessible for mssql, but I would not recommend it to perform regular backups. I'll add it to my Answer.

Comment: Yea I understand that I could do all of that with scripts and will do that if the less scripted way is too cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

With mssql running under Local System I don't think there's a direct way.

You can either

- **run mssql in a user account** (by service configuration) where you have provided and permanently stored the logon credentials or
- you can **stage the backup** to a local directory that you then copy
  or move to the NAS with an additional batch job (task scheduler or
  similar) and with explicit user logon in the batch (`net use \\nasname\sharename /user:username` with a previous `net use \\nasname\sharename /user:username /savecred` with the same user).

I'd prefer the latter, with the benefit that the backup still runs when NAS authentication fails.

Comment: Earnest question - if you go with the `net use` solution, wouldn't you be able to write the backup directly to the NAS? That is, at that point, I don't think anything in the chain cares what is writing bytes. I do agree with the robustness of "write locally and copy" though.

Comment: If you use MSSQL's native backup, the file is written by the service. If that's running as Local System you can't login to the NAS unless you find some way to run a batch script from the service.

Comment: I've had good luck doing `exec xp_cmdshell 'net use ...'` at which point the SQL service account (whatever it happens to be) should be able to access the remote share. I've done this for restore command, but not backups (though I'd expect them to work the same).

Comment: Yes, that should actually work as well. :-)